# Error While Using c3p0 Connection Pool

Tags: java, servlets, c3p0

Hi I am using c3p0 connection Pooling : My JDBC Class:

```
public static Connection connect() {
           Connection conn = null;
           ComboPooledDataSource dataSource;
           try{
               dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
               dataSource.setDriverClass( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ); //loads the jdbc driver
               dataSource.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:mysql://localhost/circuit" );
               dataSource.setUser("root");
               dataSource.setPassword("");
               dataSource.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
               dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(5);

               // the settings below are optional -- c3p0 can work with defaults
               //conn.setMinPoolSize(5);
               //conn.setAcquireIncrement(5);
               //conn.setMaxPoolSize(20);  
               conn = dataSource.getConnection();
               conn.setAutoCommit(false);
           }catch(Exception e){
              //Handle errors for Class.forName
              e.printStackTrace();
           }finally{
               return conn;            
           }//end try
        }
```

Then i have servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    logger.info("Entered doGet method of AdvisorMyAccountRequestController");
    int advisorId = 0;
    String username = "";
    //int[] id = new int[50];
    //int[] userIds = new int[];
    List<Integer> userIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //List<Integer> requestId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i= 0;
    try{
    advisorId = (int) request.getSession().getAttribute("advisorId");
    username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
    }catch(Exception e){
        response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
    }
    List<UserDetailsDTO> userDetailsList = new ArrayList<UserDetailsDTO>();
    //List<UserRequestDTO> userRequestDetails = new ArrayList<UserRequestDTO>();
    int userId = 0;
    //int requestId = 0;
    Timestamp bookingDate = null;
    if(username != null &&  advisorId != 0 && !("").equals(username))
    {
    /*  //Getting request Id from the session table where STATUS = "PENDING FOR USER PAYMENT" AND "PENDING FOR USER PAYMENT WITH NEW DATES"
        MyAccountRequestDAO requestIdList = new MyAccountRequestDAO();
        requestId = requestIdList.getRequestId(advisorId);

        if(requestId != null && requestId.size() > 0) {
            //Getting request details of the advisor from the 'session table'
            MyAccountRequestDAO requestDetails = new MyAccountRequestDAO();
            userRequestDetails = requestDetails.getRequestDetails(requestId);
            for (UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO : userRequestDetails) {
                userIds[i] = userRequestDTO.getUserId();
                i++;
            }
        }
        */

        //Getting request details of the advisor from the 'userrequest' where STATUS = "PENDING FOR ADVISOR APPROVAL" to display on the Request Tab of the Myaccount page.
        MyAccountRequestDAO dao = new MyAccountRequestDAO();
        List<UserRequestDTO> list = dao.getAdvisorRequestDetails(advisorId);
        List<UserRequestDTO> list1 = new ArrayList<UserRequestDTO>();
        List<TimeDTO> difference = new ArrayList<TimeDTO>();
        Boolean isStatusCommit = false;
        for (UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO : list) {
            String status = userRequestDTO.getStatus();
            if(("PENDING FOR ADVISOR APPROVAL").equals(status)){
                userIds.add(userRequestDTO.getUserId()) ;
                bookingDate = userRequestDTO.getBookingTime();
                GetTimeLeftForReply time = new GetTimeLeftForReply();
                difference = time.getHoursAndMinutes(bookingDate);
                if(difference.size() > 0){
                    for (TimeDTO timeDTO : difference) {
                        userRequestDTO.setDays(timeDTO.getDay());
                        userRequestDTO.setHours(timeDTO.getHours());
                        userRequestDTO.setMinutes(timeDTO.getMinutes());
                    }   
                }else{
                    userRequestDTO.setDays(0);
                    userRequestDTO.setHours(0);
                    userRequestDTO.setMinutes(0);
                /*  //If advisor has lapsed the the time to reply, then change the status of the request.
                    String status1 = "SESSION LAPSE BY ADVISOR";
                    ChangeRequestStatusDAO change = new ChangeRequestStatusDAO();
                    isStatusCommit = change.setStatus(status1,requestId);
                    userRequestDTO.setStatus(status1); */
                }
                list1.add(userRequestDTO);
            }else if (("REQUEST ACCEPTED BY ADVISOR").equals(status)) {
                userIds.add(userRequestDTO.getUserId()) ;
                userRequestDTO.setDays(0);
                userRequestDTO.setHours(0);
                userRequestDTO.setMinutes(0);
                userRequestDTO.setStatus("PENDING FOR USER PAYMENT");
                list1.add(userRequestDTO);
            }else if (("REQUEST ACCEPTED BY ADVISOR WITH NEW DATES").equals(status)) {
                userIds.add(userRequestDTO.getUserId()) ;
                i++;
                userRequestDTO.setDays(0);
                userRequestDTO.setHours(0);
                userRequestDTO.setMinutes(0);
                userRequestDTO.setStatus("PENDING FOR USER PAYMENT WITH NEW DATES");
                list1.add(userRequestDTO);
            }               
        }
        //Fetching the name of the user with id in int[] userIds.
        if(userIds.size() > 0 ){
            //Fetching user details from the uderdetails table
            UserDetailsDAO user1 = new UserDetailsDAO();
            userDetailsList = user1.getUserDetails(userIds);
        }
        request.setAttribute("list1", list1);
        //request.setAttribute("userRequestDetails", userRequestDetails);
        request.setAttribute("userDetailsList", userDetailsList);
        request.setAttribute("type", "advisor");
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/requests.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

And one of my DAO:

```
public List<UserRequestDTO> getRequestDetails(int userId){
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.info("Entered getRequestDetails method of MyAccountRequestDAO");
        List<UserRequestDTO> list = new ArrayList<UserRequestDTO>();
        PreparedStatement pstmt;
        try {
            conn =Util.connect();
            String query ="SELECT * FROM userrequest WHERE USER_ID = ?";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setInt(1, userId);
            ResultSet results = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while(results.next()){
                UserRequestDTO user =  new UserRequestDTO();
                user.setRequestId(results.getInt("REQUEST_ID"));
                user.setUserId(results.getInt("USER_ID"));
                user.setAdvisorId(results.getInt("ADVISOR_ID"));
                user.setService(results.getString("SERVICE"));
                user.setMode(results.getString("MODE_OF_COMMUNICATION"));
                user.setQuery(results.getString("QUERY"));
                user.setDuration(results.getString("DURATION"));
                user.setBookingTime(results.getTimestamp("BOOKING_TIME"));
                user.setTime1(results.getTimestamp("DATE_TIME1"));
                user.setTime2(results.getTimestamp("DATE_TIME2"));
                user.setTime3(results.getTimestamp("DATE_TIME3"));
                user.setTime4(results.getTimestamp("DATE_TIME4"));
                user.setTime5(results.getTimestamp("DATE_TIME5"));
                user.setTime6(results.getTimestamp("DATE_TIME6"));
                user.setStatus(results.getString("STATUS"));            
                list.add(user);
            }
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            try {
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                logger.error("getRequestDetails method of MyAccountRequestDAO threw error:"+e.getMessage());
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            logger.error("getRequestDetails method of MyAccountRequestDAO threw error:"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("getRequestDetails method of MyAccountRequestDAO threw error:"+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   


        logger.info("Exit getRequestDetails method of MyAccountRequestDAO");
        return list;
    }
```

When i debugged the code , the servlet is executed again and again .I guess it is somewhere going in infinite loop and
This error pops up again and again:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2032)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:66)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:76)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:66)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.assimilateResource(BasicResourcePool.java:787)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.acquireUntil(BasicResourcePool.java:548)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$000(BasicResourcePool.java:35)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:972)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@7c1b964e -- Unexpectedly Broken!!!
    While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed
    to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed
    acquisition attempts (30).
```

Finally this error is shown

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Unexpected Break Stack Trace!
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@7d80f1f2 -- Unexpectedly Broken!!!
    While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed
    to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed
    acquisition attempts (30).
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.unexpectedBreak(BasicResourcePool.java:431)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:35)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:985)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@c4767dd -- close() called multiple times.
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@c4767dd -- Unexpectedly broken!!!
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Unexpected Break Stack Trace!
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.unexpectedBreak(BasicResourcePool.java:431)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:35)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:985)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@c4767dd -- close() called multiple times.
```

Please tell me what is the problem in the code.I have just shifted my whole code in c3p0.This s where i am making a mistake.Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: How many connections do you have? The error *message from server: "Too many connections"* is fairly clear and is coming from the *server*. Make sure you don't have a leak somewhere and check your configuration.

Comment: Hi Elliott,How to check that.I have put my connection config class my servlet and one DAO Class and all my other DAO Classes  are implemented the same way as this one.So, am i doing anything wrong in this one?

Comment: It's possible that you've got one (or more) where you forgot to `close()` the connection in a finally block (but the code you posted appears to be correct in that respect). Finally, your provider may only allow 5 (or fewer) concurrent database connections. But the error is coming from the database side so check the logs there (if you can).

Comment: Hi Elliot, I have checked all my DAO classes .I have Closed the connection in the finally block in my every DAO Method.So where could i possibly go wrong?While debugging my servlet is executing again and again (It is like an infinite loop) ? Does this ring the bell?

Comment: There's more I could say, but you are running a very old version of c3p0. The first thing I'd do is upgrade (to c3p0-0.9.5-pre10, which is very near final release).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things you can do:

1. Set explicitly the max size of the connection pool:

   `conn.setMaxPoolSize(50);`
2. Check if you are closing the connection
3. Check on the server the number of connections
4. Kill unused (aged) connections using

   - maxConnectionAge
   - maxIdleTime
   - maxIdleTimeExcessConnections

From the documentation

> By default, pools will never expire Connections. If you wish
>   Connections to be expired over time in order to maintain "freshness",
>   set maxIdleTime and/or maxConnectionAge. maxIdleTime defines how many
>   seconds a Connection should be permitted to go unused before being
>   culled from the pool. maxConnectionAge forces the pool to cull any
>   Connections that were acquired from the database more than the set
>   number of seconds in the past.

Documentation:

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

Comment: I have already set the maxIdleTime.But then also it is not working.